# FirebaseAuth REST API getOobConfirmationCode not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to allow new sign up user after verify email.

So from SignUp screen, call firebase REST API as below.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=xxxx
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json

{"email":"sungyong@humminglab.io","password":"123qwe!@#","returnSecureToken":true}
```

It response as below.

> {   "kind": "identitytoolkit#SignupNewUserResponse",   "idToken":
>   "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImZmMWRmNWExNWI1Y2Y1ODJiNjFhMjEzODVjMGNmYWVkZmRiNmE3NDgiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vc2hhcnAtaW1wcmludC0yMzQ2MDYiLCJhdWQiOiJzaGFycC1pbXByaW50LTIzNDYwNiIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTU1NDExNjE3OCwidXNlcl9pZCI6IjFIQWVNd0I1dWlocG14UkwyWWZ0STRlZTl6WTIiLCJzdWIiOiIxSEFlTXdCNXVpaHBteFJMMllmdEk0ZWU5elkyIiwiaWF0IjoxNTU0MTE2MTc4LCJleHAiOjE1NTQxMTk3NzgsImVtYWlsIjoic3VuZ3lvbmdAaHVtbWluZ2xhYi5pbyIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjpmYWxzZSwiZmlyZWJhc2UiOnsiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6eyJlbWFpbCI6WyJzdW5neW9uZ0BodW1taW5nbGFiLmlvIl19LCJzaWduX2luX3Byb3ZpZGVyIjoicGFzc3dvcmQifX0.L98zHgGAQh1ezPDyqxO9k7RXfLXjU7Zad5Xf-uscitTRNMQJOon2SSUwfKcrf48rFoa2y9c7Gb7DsscUSBxwfRi_C6-ObLwF1uoh0xuoQl68gsQqLfqJfeudGaY5IquW-UWfiBAN8DeClTms1K842FXLI6fEoYFplPIg39jUpwYtCnqfevXuWFeI_Y3taO5NWwEnO1VjsURgt_mmGGTKosoJKTTcKgv3hjgm7nb7whyYUylGimxtxoUtsTCHnYKQHrxkOiW7-rdTpfPo39tWB8uYRcPBVmYUozAi2NDlfpnlJ-Sb9noEv7eRIoC3Vk1oyzwctaU2VhNj67IRHFhufQ",
>   "email": "sungyong@humminglab.io",   "refreshToken":
>   "AEu4IL1WfTJX3yXu_iW9gWJYjI6cz-YN6h1AUNDT7h1Hc1KcbebmCUa9SFOjn1uMvME4HVU9IbKWnY0YJSgSSt4fhpdYxipo9yebSe_cQc-w_UNZ9W4EuIpQh3zOBIG7Ys6oB284JTMiH5oCuzE9MMm_tqoib5iLcC7hvP0_YUhcbDOhhEECh2cV1jv3iIy_F7fMTHyt-jEhdOa057oQuxCYaOI9LL9dX6snXIFAEIhhllhIrIIgqcc",
>   "expiresIn": "3600",   "localId": "1HAeMwB5uihpmxRL2YftI4ee9zY2" }

Because `signupNewUser` doesn't send verification email, I manually called `getOobConfirmationCode` like below.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/getOobConfirmationCode?key=xxx
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json

{
  "requestType":"VERIFY_EMAIL",
  "idToken":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImZmMWRmNWExNWI1Y2Y1ODJiNjFhMjEzODVjMGNmYWVkZmRiNmE3NDgiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vc2hhcnAtaW1wcmludC0yMzQ2MDYiLCJhdWQiOiJzaGFycC1pbXByaW50LTIzNDYwNiIsImF1dGhfdGltZSI6MTU1NDExNjE3OCwidXNlcl9pZCI6IjFIQWVNd0I1dWlocG14UkwyWWZ0STRlZTl6WTIiLCJzdWIiOiIxSEFlTXdCNXVpaHBteFJMMllmdEk0ZWU5elkyIiwiaWF0IjoxNTU0MTE2MTc4LCJleHAiOjE1NTQxMTk3NzgsImVtYWlsIjoic3VuZ3lvbmdAaHVtbWluZ2xhYi5pbyIsImVtYWlsX3ZlcmlmaWVkIjpmYWxzZSwiZmlyZWJhc2UiOnsiaWRlbnRpdGllcyI6eyJlbWFpbCI6WyJzdW5neW9uZ0BodW1taW5nbGFiLmlvIl19LCJzaWduX2luX3Byb3ZpZGVyIjoicGFzc3dvcmQifX0.L98zHgGAQh1ezPDyqxO9k7RXfLXjU7Zad5Xf-uscitTRNMQJOon2SSUwfKcrf48rFoa2y9c7Gb7DsscUSBxwfRi_C6-ObLwF1uoh0xuoQl68gsQqLfqJfeudGaY5IquW-UWfiBAN8DeClTms1K842FXLI6fEoYFplPIg39jUpwYtCnqfevXuWFeI_Y3taO5NWwEnO1VjsURgt_mmGGTKosoJKTTcKgv3hjgm7nb7whyYUylGimxtxoUtsTCHnYKQHrxkOiW7-rdTpfPo39tWB8uYRcPBVmYUozAi2NDlfpnlJ-Sb9noEv7eRIoC3Vk1oyzwctaU2VhNj67IRHFhufQ"
}
```

But it responed with status code 400.

> That’s an error. Your client has issued a malformed or illegal
>   request. That’s all we know

I don't know why it failed.  I double checked `idToken` which I received by signup api.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Did you solve it? I don't see an issue using verify email and using it from past 1 year.

Comment: No, I choose another way that use firebase auth api.  My frontend call `createUser(properties: admin.auth.CreateRequest): Promise<admin.auth.UserRecord>;` directly.

Comment: I'm also having an issue with this endpoint, in my case I want to bypass the e-mail process, because I'm sending by myself the verification e-mail (to be able to customize it), so I'm trying to call `getOobConfirmationCode`, but it's not return a `oobCode`, instead it just send a verification e-mail